# Use jQuery to show/hide div based on numeric input quantity

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd be most appreciative if anybody could help me with this please.

I have the following input:

```
 <input onchange="UpdateItemQuantity(this.value,1284349,0,10352185,2579246,'','AU'); return false;" type="number" class="form-control cart-quantity" min="1" value="1"/>
```

I'd like to have a div display a message underneath if the input value is increased to 3 or more?

Project Context:
Customer will add items to the cart and if they reach 3, they receive a free product

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This actually depends on how you counting the cart value. Is it going to be counted by strings or integers

Answer (score 1):

In your `html` add a `div` below `input`:

`<div id="free-prod"><p>You have a free product</p></div>`

In CSS:

```
#free-prod {
    display:none
}
```

In your `UpdateItemQuantity` function  just add the following code:

```
if(this.value >2) {
     $('#free-prod').show();
}
else{
    $('#free-prod').hide();
}
```

***EDIT:***

If you can edit the `UpdateItemQuantity` function (as said in comment). You can add a event listner to the element. I'd suggest giving some `id` to your `input` element and do

```
if($('#your_input_id').val() > 2 ) {
     $('#free-prod').show();
}
$('#your_input_id').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() > 2 ) {
        $('#free-prod').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#free-prod').hide();
    }
})
```

***Demo*** https://jsfiddle.net/w8vwsx81/

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Your solution looks great. My only problem is I'm using Adobe Business catalyst which automatically populates the UpdateItemQuanity function. So I need to add it as a script at the bottom of the page. Is this possible. Thank you again

Comment: Thanks again. It's working fine now. Only issue now is if I alter the quantity multiple times the div no longer shows up?

Comment: Is this something to do with jQuery not loading again after first instance?

Comment: nope..it should be fine as along as you're putting it in `$(document).ready(...)` as shown in the demo

Answer (score 0):

This demo show that (and how) the concept works.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.quantity').on('input', function() {
        var states = ['hide','show'],    //possible states of the freebie div
            i = +this.value > 2 ? 1 : 0; //determine index of the states array
        $('.freebie')[states[i]]();      //example $('.freebie')['hide']() is equiv to $('.freebie').hide()
    })
    .trigger('input');
    //when using buttons to increment and decrement
    $('.increase,.decrease').on('click', function() {
        var diff = $(this).is('.increase') ? 1 : -1; //determin whether to decrement or increment
        $('.quantity').val(function() {
            return +this.value + diff; //decrement or increment
        });
        $('.quantity').trigger('input'); //manually trigger the 'input' event or whatever event triggers the freebies div to show
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="decrease">-</button>
<input type="number" class="quantity" value="0"> 
<button type="button" class="increase">+</button>
<div class="freebie">
    <img src="http://momsneedtoknow.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/freebies.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much.  It's working fine when I enter the amount directly. What about if I have the + - next to the input? It doesn't seem to trigger code when I use those?

Comment: <button class="increase">+</button>

Comment: Manually trigger the event once the value is incremented or decremented ..... $('.quantity').trigger('input');

Comment: See updated code ... showing how to manually trigger the `input` event upon qty change.

Comment: Thank you again. That's terrific! Much appreciated!

Comment: Please upvote this answer if you found it useful, and accept it if you consider it the answer you were looking for. Enjoy!